# Capturing object dependencies at execution time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any sane way to capture execution-time object dependencies in SQL Server?

For instance, take this dynamic SQL scenario:

```
DECLARE @table SYSNAME = 'SomeTable'
DECLARE @column SYSNAME = 'SomeColumn'
DECLARE @proc SYSNAME
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP 1 @proc = '+@column+' FROM '+@table
EXEC sp_executesql @command, N'@proc SYSNAME OUTPUT', @proc OUTPUT
EXEC @proc
```

The execution-time dependencies would be `SomeTable`, `sp_executesql`, the value of `@proc`, and whatever objects are referenced *at run-time* by the @proc procedure.

Methods I have considered thus far:

- grabbing the xml query plan from sys.dm_exec_query_plan from within each batch, and passing it off to another process via service broker for processing. pros: I think it might actually work. cons: potentially expensive, and intrusive: each batch and execution level must be retrofitted to capture the query plan.
- extended events. pros: if it could be made to work, then great! cons: I don't think there is a suitable event class for "object access", eg scan and/or seek and/or exec etc etc.

Ideally, the capture would work something like this:

```
DECLARE @guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
EXEC usp_begin_object_capture @guid OUTPUT

DECLARE @table SYSNAME = 'SomeTable'
DECLARE @column SYSNAME = 'SomeColumn'
DECLARE @proc SYSNAME
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP 1 @proc = '+@column+' FROM '+@table
EXEC sp_executesql @command, N'@proc SYSNAME OUTPUT', @proc OUTPUT
EXEC @proc

EXEC usp_stop_object_capture @guid

SELECT object_name FROM object_capture_table WHERE guid = @guid

------------------------------
object_name 
------------------------------
SomeTable
sp_executesql
<proc_named_by_@proc>
<object1_referenced_by_@proc>
<object2_referenced_by_@proc>
<object3_referenced_by_@proc>
<objectn_referenced_by_@proc>
```

Context:

I am trying to cache/memoize the deterministic result sets of long-running procedures. The underlying data is fairly static. If I could gather actual dependencies at execution-time, I could automatically associate an entry in the cache with a set of objects. If any of those objects changed, I would know which entries to invalidate.

This may be a poor caching strategy, I don't know. But the dependency technique would still be useful in other contexts.

Any thoughts? Many thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to override SQL Server's own caching?

Comment: I'm trying to cache/memoize deterministic result sets of long-running procedures. I don't believe SQL Server maintains such a cache. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answering my own question....]

See the sp_trace% system procs, beginning w/ [sp_trace_create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190362.aspx).

Use event 114, "Audit Schema Object Access Event".

Include columns `DatabaseName`, `ParentName` and `ObjectName`, and perhaps `ServerName`.

Filter on column 12, `SPID`.

Extended events don't expose the schema object access event (yet), otherwise it might be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

How about leveraging the SQL Server built-in mechanism for cache invalidation, namely [Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/)? You cache/memoize your query result, and let SQL Server itself notify you when a result has changed.

Comment: Two questions: a) Is this even possible from within SQL Server? BOL claims you cannot subscribe to query notification from within the server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188669.aspx). b) Does query notification for EXECUTE statements gather its dependencies at execution time, for each nested batch as it gets compiled? Many restrictions apply to SELECT statement. It's not obvious how these translate over to EXECUTE statements from the documentation, but AFAIK, not even flow control is allowed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx).

Thank you for the link.

Comment: I'm afraid this is as good as it gets with regards to keeping cached results. For something that tracks object references during a T-SQL snippet execution, you should consider setting up an XEvents session. Whether is possible to have a save and correct cache invalidation based on tracking object references, that remains to be see, but it would be quite a feats of strength if you pull it off.

Comment: I went old-skool, w/ sp_trace%. Now I have run-time dependencies. Half way there!